# present simple plus past simple in the if-clause

Tags: grammar, past-tense, syntactic-analysis

Please help me understand whether I can use the past simple tense with the present simple tense in one if-clause.

My example is the question that I want to ask when speaking with English native speakers:

> Would it be odd to you if I do not say "bless you" when you sneezed loudly and keep silence instead?

Is it wrong to use 'would be' followed by present simple phrase 'I do not say'?

Comment: This kind of use of *would* in the consequent demands *did* in the conditional.  This is different from *Would you mind if I listen in?* where you have the “willful” *would* not the *would* of simple probability as in your case.

Comment: @tchrist Really? It doesn’t to me, at least not in certain contexts. “Would it be okay if I leave now?” is perfectly fine and natural to me, as is “If I give you the money, would you get me a sandwich from the cafeteria?”. In non-questions, it doesn’t work as well: “If I leave now, it would be okay” requires quite a lot more context and forcing to work—with no context, I’d call it ungrammatical. On the other hand, if you use the present “if I _don’t_”, then you **must** also use “when you _sneeze_” in the present.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanations. So you advise me not to use this structure in this kind of sentences, tchrist.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet If you keep asking me hard questions, I’m going to have to put another pot of coffee on. :)   Maybe it is that when the *if* comes after the *would* that the present tense works, but when the *if* comes first, it may not.  Shucks, I dunno.

Comment: I have read all of your answers. Thanks a lot for the explanations. So you advise me not to use this structure in this kind of sentences, tchrist.However, you think that this structure sounds ok in an interrogative sentence, Janus. Thank you for the correction of my mistake.

Comment: @Kate I actually don’t know if it’s “wrong”, Kate, nor even whether it would be unacceptable. I need more coffee.

Comment: I think the main difference between [*"If I **paid** you, would you {do something I want}?"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22if+I+paid+you+would+you%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) and [*If I **pay** you, would you {do it}?*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22if+I+pay+you+would+you%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) isn't so much a matter of *grammar* (pedantry here, IMHO) as of *nuance*. Using past tense (even more so, using subjunctive *"If I **were to pay...**"*) casts the hypothetical action further away from "present reality". More an enquiry than an offer.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, FambleFingers. Adhering to the strict grammar rule is not so important here. I have come to the conclusion that I can use this structure in some cases. Moreover, I wanted to emphasize rather the closeness to reality, formulating my question in this way.

Comment: The question as posed in the body of the OP is well-written, polite, grammatically correct, and understood by native listeners for the content and context. "Would it be all right for you if I do not add this as an answer?"

Comment: The tenses should be at least ***consistent***: *do ... sneeze ... keep*, *do ... have sneezed ... keep*, or *did ... sneezed ... kept* all sound fine to me. But *present ... past ... present* is wrong.

Comment: Being essentially a question of grammar, one is expected to say point blank "it is wrong." However, Kate, please note that this is ELU, where seasoned language pundits muddy the waters all the time (as is the English language so merrily lends itself to).  Please visit [ell.se] instead. Just my 2c.

Comment: The sentence in its entirety is confusing because it seems to be a conditional that's (retroactively) asking about an event ("sneezed") past. I would rewrite it as: "Is it odd to you that I did not say "bless you" when you [had] sneezed and kept silent instead?". I should add that if you changed _sneezed_ to _sneeze_ along with changing _do_ to _did_ and _keep_ to _kept_, it would work.

Answer (score 3):

As is often the case, I get the feeling that "Is it wrong to do X"?" is perhaps not the most useful question to ask about a sentence such as yours:

> Would it be odd to you if I do not say "bless you" when you sneezed loudly and keep silence instead?

Hearers and readers can work their way through a labyrinth of syntactical structures that might defeat a purely logical mechanical interpreter. Nevertheless, as I look at the example sentence, I get a feeling of vague disquiet because the wording forces me as a reader into making a more complicated series of interpretive adjustments than I would like in order to come to terms with so straightforward an underlying idea.

My advice would be to put "I do" and "[I] keep" into past tense for the greater interpretive comfort of your hearers or readers:

> Would it be odd to you if I did not say "bless you" when you sneezed loudly, but kept silent instead?

or even more lucidly:

> Would it seem odd to you if, instead of saying "bless you" when you sneezed loudly, I remained silent?